# Can MHC class I be used for presenting peptides of extracellular origin by non-professional APCs?

Tags: immunology, antigen, mhc

Wikipedia says that: "The antigens presented by **MHC class II** are derived from **extracellular proteins** (not **cytosolic** as in **MHC class I**)."

So does this mean that **MHC class I cannot be used** for peptides derived from **phagocytosis** by non-professional APCs? (i.e. peptides that of extracellular origin?).

For example, when non-professional APCs that can undergo phagocytosis (Eosinophil, neutrophil, dendritic cell) engulf bacteria, will they present their antigens using MHC I although the peptides are of extracellular origin? or will they not present any MHC at all? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> when non-professional APCs that can undergo phagocytosis (Eosinophil, neutrophil, dendritic cell) engulf bacteria

Dendritic cells and probably neutrophils are professional APC, so this part of the question is a little confusing.

You're asking about [cross-presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-presentation), which is the process by which extracellular antigen can be presented to CD8 T cells on MHC class I.  Cross-presentation is mainly performed by certain sub-classes of dendritic cell. A number of other cell types have been shown to be capable of it, but it's not clear how important they are in vivo.

A decent review of cross-presentation is [Understanding the Biology of Antigen Cross-Presentation for the Design of Vaccines Against Cancer](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3986565/).  A review of a related but somewhat different concept (MHC recycling) is [Endocytic Recycling of MHC Class I Molecules in Non-professional Antigen Presenting and Dendritic Cells](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6330327/).